# TypeScript: Get type from a nested type

Tags: typescript, types, nested

I have a type (Note: Both `a` and `foo` can be optional):

```js
type Something = {
  a?: {
    foo?: {
      bar: {
        c: {
          id: string,
          countryCode: number,
          animal: { ... }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to have another type `MyType`, which is `bar` in the example above. So `MyType` will be:

```js
type MyType = {
  c: {
    id: string,
    countryCode: number,
    animal: { ... }
  }
}
```

My question: How could I create `MyType` from `type Something`?

Update: See this comment for the answer: [TypeScript: Get type from a nested type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76333795/typescript-get-type-from-a-nested-type?noredirect=1#comment134607414_76333795)

Comment: `type MyType = Something["a"]["foo"]["bar"]`

Comment: @Woohaik One level `Something["a"]` is fine, however in the next level TypeScript will complain `Property 'foo' does not exist on type ...` (ts 2339).

Comment: @IamX I can't reproduce it [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvxbMN). Can you include the code how you actually extract the type?

Comment: @wonderflame My fault. Updated my question. The change: Both `a` and `foo` properties can be optional. Then you can reproduce it.

Comment: The easiest way would be: `type MyType = NonNullable<NonNullable<Something["a"]>["foo"]>["bar"];
`

Comment: @IamX your right, I did even see the `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be:
`type MyType = NonNullable<NonNullable<Something["a"]>["foo"]>["bar"];`

However, I can suggest a more dynamic approach as well:

```
type Something = {
  a?: {
    foo?: {
      bar: {
        c: {
          id: string;
          countryCode: number;
        };
      };
    };
  };
};

type RetrieveSubProperty<T, K extends string[]> = [] extends K
  ? T
  : K extends [infer First extends keyof T, ...infer Rest extends string[]]
  ? RetrieveSubProperty<NonNullable<T[First]>, Rest>
  : never;

type Bar = RetrieveSubProperty<Something, ["a", "foo", "bar"]>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMoF4oDeAUFFAIYD8AXISaVAGZxzW330BGZATjce+wDGfOgPpoAJjQDOwbpiwBuUWKiC4AVwxyQAYTgSINDBoQcI3ZaqgBfKwLsrHpR46KhIUAErJ5EAG4QMBocAArccJDcoAA8ACoANFAA0lAQAB7AEBgS0lCy8tgA2gC6AHx4UKVpmdm5KXQUUHF0NKkZWTl5RZgMFlAAYmjcsjWd9QDWECBwDM1JAHRLvf0+ox11eQUKpSWN3r5oAUEh4ZEWsQBycBiXGgA292Qc9xDxRUMjwOVJa8BlrSgGGOliI7nA0AAQjxKj45EdAsEwhEorF4EhUAokkUAERkHFJHFMOAEqA4rjcHHlZQAehppAAehQgA)